# How to get text from textView in the app in robotframework

Tags: android, python, apk, appium, robotframework

I have imported appium library in robot framework and I can access UI as below

```
click button    Test
click element    id=testId
```

But I don't see any method to get text from textView.
DO they have anything similay to find element by id or xpath, etc in robot framework?

I am trying to use should be equal on text from textView

Comment: I see page should contain method but is there better way than that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you really spent much time looking into this?  There's keywords in popular libraries that do exactly what you wish, unless I'm missing a special nuance?

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html or http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute should suffice for your needs.

Here's a similar solution I needed at one time:

```
${image_text}=    Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute    ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/tbody/tr/td/div/img@alt
```

Why don't you see if you can adapt the above to your needs?  Or better yet, there's a keyword from the XML library for this exact situation:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Element%20Text